# Grails static mapping fails (repeated id)

Tags: grails, mapping, grails-orm

I'm trying to do reverse engineering and create a model class for a given table schema in a database.

The table's name is `infopac_usersProva` and it has two columns:

- strCip varchar(15) which is the id
- USERNM varchar(75)

I have written the model like this:

```
    class Infopac_usersProva {

       String strCip 
       String usernm

       static mapping={
        datasource 'gpaq'
        table 'infopac_usersProva'
        version false
        columns{
            id column: 'strCip'
            usernm column: 'USERNM', sqlType: "varchar(75)"
            strCip column: 'strCip', sqlType: "varchar(15)"
        }
       }

       static constraints = {
        strCip (nullable:true, insert:false, update:false)
       }
    }
```

But I get this error:

> Repeated column in mapping for entity: edu.upc.gpaq.domain.generic.Infopac_usersProva column: strCip (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

I need to specify the column name for strCip because if I take out that line the model is trying to fetch str_cip instead of strCip. And if I take out "id column: 'strCip' then I get an error saying that there is no id column.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can get rid of `strCip` definition.
Instead define the id field properly.

See if this works for you:

```
class Infopac_usersProva {

String usernm

static mapping={
    datasource 'gpaq'
    table 'infopac_usersProva'
    version false
    columns{
        id generator: 'assigned', name: 'strCip', type: 'string'
        usernm column: 'USERNM', sqlType: "varchar(75)"
    }
}
```

*I didn't check this...*

Comment: +1 you may also need to explicitly declare a `String id` property.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I ended up doing this:

Comment: You're welcome. If you meant to include your final solution in your comment - it was cut off. Please edit your post and put it there.

Answer (score 0):

This one should work:

```
class Infopack_usersProva {
    String strCip
    String usernm

    static constraints = {
        strCip(nullable: false, maxSize: 15)
        usernm(nullable: true, maxSize: 75)
    }

    static mapping = {
        datasource('gpaq')
        table('infopac_usersProva')
        version(false)
        autoTimestamp(false)
        usernm(column: 'USERNM')
        strCip(column: 'strCip')
        id(column: 'strCip', name: 'strCip', generator: 'assigned')
    }
}
```

But it has `strCip` as not null. But AFAIK you need an id column that is not null so i do not see any way around this. At least with grails/hibernate.

And if you want `strCip` never be included in any `save()` you need to specify

```
strCip(column: 'strCip', insertable: false, updateable: false)
```

in the mappings block. I am not aware of any constraints called `insert`or `update` and would expect them to just get ignored there.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following (see the bold text)

```
class Infopac_usersProva {

  String usernm
  String id

  static mapping={
    datasource 'gpaq'
    table 'infopac_usersProva'
    version false
    autoTimestamp false
    columns{
        **id column: 'strCip', sqlType: "varchar(15)"**
        usernm column: 'USERNM', sqlType: "varchar(75)"
    }
  }

  static constraints = {

  }
}
```

It works now. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Might be a little late for this, but you need to use the updateable and insertable properties instead.  It worked for me:

```
class Infopac_usersProva {

   String strCip 
   String usernm

   static mapping={
    datasource 'gpaq'
    table 'infopac_usersProva'
    version false
    columns{
        id column: 'strCip'
        usernm column: 'USERNM', sqlType: "varchar(75)"
        strCip column: 'strCip', updateable: false, insertable: false
    }
   }
}
```